# meteor currently active users?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a simple chatroom in meteor. How would I get a list of currently active users? Is there a way to actually get a list of current connections / clients?

Comment: u can put a field like active in current user, when it's login or enter specify room change hes active status.

Comment: @crapthings what about when he disconnects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I browsed the meteor sources yesterday to see if there is already anything like that. I couldn't find a connected flag or anything...

I think you'll have two options:

- **Implement a heartbeat in the client and the server for every connected user.** I personally don't like this idea very much, as this could result in zillions of intervals running on your server.
- **Use the *sockjs* server to get the open sockets**.  `Meteor.default_server.stream_server.all_sockets()` returns an array with all opened sockets. You could than have a single interval looking for changes in that (or better you'll listen to changes of the sockjs server itself, there is a `register` method that could be useful), map the open sockets with your users and use a collection to push it to your clients.
  Each client knows his socket id, so the mapping shouldnt be to hard.

I didn't implement it yet, so these are only ideas where to start.

Comment: While this answer is great (I was also looking for this for quite a while) it's 2019 and I wonder why Meteor does not give us a official solution yet...

Comment: it's now Meteor.server and no more Meteor.default_server

Comment: On Meteor 2.2...seems like both are still available. Do you know if there's a difference?0

Also, looks like it's now `Meteor.default_server.stream_server.open_sockets` which is an Array of `SockJSConnections` itselves and not a `fn`

Comment: I'm on METEOR@2.5.1 and Meteor.server.stream_server.all_sockets() works

Answer (score 1):

I created a REST endpoint to expose the number of current active users...

**/server/main.js**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker'

Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json())

Picker.route('/api/status', ({ provider }, request, response) => {
  response.statusCode = 200
  response.end(JSON.stringify({
    active_users: Meteor.default_server.stream_server.all_sockets().length
  }))
})
```

**Output**

> {"active_users":1}

Comment: Know of any way to close a WS connection received from `all_sockets()` ?