# Meteor: display list of current users for document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a list of documents in meteor that only authorised users can access. It's kind of like google docs. Is there an easy way to get a list of users which are currently viewing them?

I thought of including a "currentUsers" field in my mongodb object, and push/remove users whenever users view or stop viewing the component. This feels like a strange way to do it since data is persisted and is probably prone to errors since it doesn't exactly represent users currently viewing the component at a moment in time

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042550/meteor-currently-active-users) is kind of what I'm looking for, but the answer is a little old, and I'm not sure how to go about using sockjs either. If someone can provide a working example that will be great.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hope this question helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800136/how-to-count-the-current-number-of-subscriptions-to-a-meteor-publication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find that like this-

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('userList');
  }
});
```

More can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945596/7669635).

Answer (score 4):

There are several options:

DIY solution - storing data in Collection

package meteor-user-status
https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

package mrt:spy (which seems to be deprecated, but maybe you can build on top of it)
https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/spy

socket.io
https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client

Comment: mizzao:user-status - what a neat package! Hadn't seen that one before. I'd probably combine that one with persistent sessions, use the callbacks from user-status to increment / decrement counters and/or user ids. You'd have to reset these counters in Meteor.startup() on system reboot.